# calling a web service with httpMethod (POST) in swift 4.1

Tags: ios, swift, http-method, urlrequest

Let me describe view controller (page design) first. I have added one button and one label. And a function is created by me for the button. Here is the `ViewController.swift` file:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var btnHitWebService: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblResult: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    @IBAction func btnHitWebServiceClick(_ sender: Any) {
        if (getTokenWithPostMethod() == true)
        {
            lblResult.text = "yes, we get token: " + g_token
        }
        else
        {
            lblResult.text = "there is an error, please try again later"
        }
    }

    func getTokenWithPostMethod() -> Bool{

        var funcResult = false

        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://apiABCDEFG.com/token")!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        let postString = "grant_type=password&username=ABCDEF&password=ABCDEF"
        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
        request.addValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request)
        {
            data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else
            {
                // check for fundamental networking error
                print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
                return
            }

            if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200
            {
                // check for http errors
                print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                print("response = \(String(describing: response))")
            }

            do
            {
                if let jsonObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String:AnyObject]
                {
                    g_token = (jsonObject["access_token"] as? String)!
                    print(g_token)
                    g_token_type = (jsonObject["token_type"] as? String)!
                    print("\n")
                    print(g_token_type)
                    funcResult = true ;
                }
            }
            catch let error as NSError
            {
                print(error)
            }
        }

        task.resume()
        return funcResult
    }
}
```

Here is my problem: When I click button, it gives me a token in output screen in Xcode (print) but `getTokenWithPostMethod()` method returns false. Why does it return false? During the debug process, it jumps from `let task =` to `task.resume()`. Thanks! (by the way I can't share correct link, username and password. I hope these 3 are not necessary to fix this problem)

Comment: Can you try to return when you set it funcResult true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making an API call. It takes time to return the value. Here return statement will not wait for response. you should use either closure or delegate. You can try the given code:

```
func getTokenWithPostMethod(handler: @escaping (_ funcResult: Bool) -> Void){

    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://apiABCDEFG.com/token")!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let postString = "grant_type=password&username=ABCDEF&password=ABCDEF"
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
    request.addValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request)
    {
        data, response, error in
        var funcResult = false

        if error == nil, let data = data {
            do
            {
                if let jsonObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String:AnyObject]
                {
                    g_token = (jsonObject["access_token"] as? String)!
                    print(g_token)
                    g_token_type = (jsonObject["token_type"] as? String)!
                    print("\n")
                    print(g_token_type)
                    funcResult = true
                }
            }
            catch let error as NSError
            {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        // edited
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            handler(funcResult)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

This will return after the response comes. Replace the calling of that method with :

```
@IBAction func btnHitWebServiceClick(_ sender: Any) {

    getTokenWithPostMethod { (flag) in
        if flag {
            lblResult.text = "yes, we get token: " + g_token
        } else {
            lblResult.text = "there is an error, please try again later"
        }
    }
}
```

For more details please [visit](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html)

Comment: Thanks but when i click button it gives this error : "UILabel.text must be used from main thread only" on this line : ' self.lblResult.text = "yes, we get token: " + g_token'  @Chanchal Chauhan

Comment: I have just noticed that i see token value in label after some minutes pass @ChanchalChauhan

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please check `//edited` code. This will update your label on main thread. Delay in label update is due to API call. You can have correct value after getting response. Please try updated code and let me know if you have problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is returning false because, you have set var funcResult = false in starting, so before URLSession request to server and return some data in response only, your function returns the funcResult value.

you can add below code inside URLSession task body, immediately after try catch, instead of adding it inside btnHitWebServiceClick :

```
if (getTokenWithPostMethod() == true)
    {
        lblResult.text = "yes, we get token: " + g_token
    }
    else
    {
        lblResult.text = "there is an error, please try again later"
    }
```

Comment: but i see token value in 'All output' window in xcode but same time i get false return from method. But i set 'funcResult = true ;' in success scope.

Comment: @mannyCalavera, you can see token value in all output, thats true, but it will take time for API call to get response, in mean while you get response, your method return false. so you need to add your if condition only after you get response.

Comment: Now i understood. Thanks for reply @Krishna Maru